# AttributeError: class Prolog has no attribute 'dynamic'

Tags: python, swi-prolog

I've installed **pyswip** on ubuntu and I followed the official documentation to do so. However, I'm still getting some issues, I found some workarounds for a couple of them and I'm still fighting with more.

Here is the code and error I'm currently getting:

```
>>> from pyswip import Prolog, registerForeign, Variable, Functor
>>> registerForeign(ask_question,name='ask', arity=1)
1
>>> hypothesize = Functor("hypothesize",1)
>>> Test = Variable()
>>> assertz = Functor('assertz',1)
>>> Prolog.dynamic("yes/1, no/1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class Prolog has no attribute 'dynamic'
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should create instance first - `prolog = Prolog()` ? and later `prolog.dynamic(...)` ?

Comment: or maybe you created own class `Prolog` which doesn't have `dynamic` ?

Comment: Are you sure the dynamic exists in pyswip? Can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @furas I tried creating instance before using prolog = Prolog() and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @F.Leone yes it does it worked fine on a colleague's computer ..

Comment: it  looks like class `Prolog` was redefined or you use differend version - you can see what method has `Prolog` using `print(dir(Prolog))` or try `help(Prolog)`

Comment: @furas I used the command you posted and it does not look like dynamic is defined in the Prolog class as claimed (['_QueryWrapper', '__doc__', '__module__', 'asserta', 'assertz', 'consult', 'query']).

Actually, I always get this when I run pyswip outside the pyswip cloned project:
>>> import pyswip
libpl (shared) not found. Possible reasons:
1) SWI-Prolog not installed as a shared library. Install SWI-Prolog (5.6.34 works just fine)
Any hints on how to fix this?

Comment: you can check what file is loaded - print( Prolog.__file__ ) and check what you have in this file. I checked source code on github and there is method `dynamic()`

Comment: btw: you can see [source code on github](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/blob/master/pyswip/prolog.py)

Comment: thnx @furas yes I looked at the documentation but nothing useful. and btw the __file__  is not working.. But thank you very much for the help!

Comment: you can also try `pyswip.__file__`

Comment: thnx @furas that worked.